# I want to communicate normally with Container Inscance in the backend pool of Application Gateway even if the Private IP changes

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-container-instances

In my environment, A Container Instance in the backend pool of the Application Gateway changes its Private IP when it is restarted.
Therefore, the communication from the frontend is interrupted every time it is restarted.

Is there a way to communicate with Application Gateway even if the private IP of Container Instance changes?
For example, activity log alerts detect the restart of Container Instance, and Automation runbook changes the routing rule of Application Gateway.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**I tested in my environment there is no change in private ip address after the container instance restarting.**

Found one SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612013/attaching-a-private-static-ip-address-to-azure-container-instance) it is stating like below mention

> When putting ACI into a subnet, your best bet may be to use subnets of
> the smallest required size - and only use one ACI per subnet.
>
> Except for checking if the IP has changed after a container has been
> restarted, I don't believe there is a real workaround here.