# Need solution for set private static ip for azure container instance

Tags: azure, containers, private, azure-container-instances, static-ip-address

Need solution for set private static ip for azure container instance. If the container restarts are reupdated

I tried many docs to fix this ,but still cant able to fix it

Tried with network security group to reserve and block the ip

Tried with the script get retrieve the ip and used in the application gateway

Tried with Public ip with the nat gateway

Answer (score 0):

> Need solution for set private static ip for azure container instance. If the container restarts are reupdated

Thanks to `silent` for suggesting the same.

Private static IP for `Azure Container Instances` is not supported.

Alternatively, you can achieve it by creating a new subnet with a smaller size **(10.4.0.0/29 - 8 address count)**, which will only provide **8 IP** addresses and Azure reserved five **IP** addresses by default and the remaining **3** **IP** addresses. However, there is still no guarantee.

[image]

Refer to the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway)  & [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612013/attaching-a-private-static-ip-address-to-azure-container-instance) by `silent` for more about `Private Static IP` for `Azure Container Instances

Comment: Thanks, Already i have tried this option ,but its has 3 ip left ,when we restart container instance it takes randomly 3 ips .But need the 1 ip static .Any option to  block the remaining 2 ips ?

Comment: No, Private static IP for Azure Container Instances is not supported.

Comment: Can we use Network interface  to set static ip for the container instance

Comment: Azure Container Instances do not support assigning private static IP address directly to the container instance using a network interface.

Comment: So no solution for this ?